# Getting the HTML content of an iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I'm currently trying to customize OpenCms (java-based open source CMS) a bit, which is using the FCKEditor embedded, which is what I'm trying access using js / jQuery.

I try to fetch the html content of the iframe, however, always getting null as a return.
This is how I try to fetch the html content from the iframe:

```
var editFrame = document.getElementById('ta_OpenCmsHtml.LargeNews_1_.Teaser_1_.0___Frame');
alert( $(editFrame).attr('id') );         // returns the correct id
alert( $(editFrame).contents().html() );  // returns null (!!)
```

Looking at the screenshot, the what I want to access is the 'LargeNews1/Teaser' html section, which currently holds the values "Newsline en...".
Below you can also see the html structure in Firebug.

However, `$(editFrame).contents().html()` returns null and I can't figure out why, whereas `$(editFrame).attr('id')` returns the correct id.

The iframe content / FCKEditor is on the same site/domain, no cross-site issues.

[image]

HTML code of iframe is at http://pastebin.com/hPuM7VUz

**Updated:**

Here's a solution that works:

```
var editArea = document.getElementById('ta_OpenCmsHtml.LargeNews_1_.Teaser_1_.0___Frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('xEditingArea');                        
$(editArea).find('iframe:first').contents().find('html:first').find('body:first').html('some <b>new</b><br/> value');
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`.contents().html()` doesn't work to get the HTML code of an IFRAME. You can do the following to get it:

```
$(editFrame).contents().find("html").html();
```

That should return all the HTML in the IFRAME for you. Or you can use "body" or "head" instead of "html" to get those sections too.

Comment: Thanks, many useful replies altogether; I edited my question and added the final solution at the bottom.

Comment: This works on Firefox, but not chrome. I just get <HEAD></HEAD><BODY></BODY>.

Answer (score 7):

you can get the content as

```
$('#iframeID').contents().find('#someID').html();
```

but frame should be in the same domain refer http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest replacing the first line with:

```
  var editFrame = $('#ta_OpenCmsHtml.LargeNews_1_.Teaser_1_.0___Frame');
```

...and the 2nd alert expression with:

```
  editFrame.html()
```

If, on the other hand, you prefer to accomplish the same w/o jquery (much cooler, IMHO) could use only JavaScript:

```
  var editFrame = document.getElementById('ta_OpenCmsHtml.LargeNews_1_.Teaser_1_.0___Frame');
  alert(editFrame.innerHTML);
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't play well with DIVs that have dots . in the id, and I cannot change the id of the FCKEditor component (easily) unfortunately. I will the test above suggestions and will post the resolution later, which I finally used. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

After trying a number of `jQuery` solutions that recommended using the option below, I discovered I was unable to get the actual `<html>` content including the parent tags.

`$("#iframeId").contents().find("html").html()`

This worked much better for me and I was able to fetch the entire `<html>...</html>` iframe content as a string.

`document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

I think the FCKEditor has its own API see http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8368

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jQuery doesn't provide a method to fetch the entire HTML of an iFrame, however since it provides access to the native DOM element, a hybrid approach is possible:

`$("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML;`

This will return iFrame's HTML including `<THTML>`, `<HEAD>` and `<BODY>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your iframe:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" aria-describedby="cke_88" title="Rich text editor, content" src="" tabindex="-1" allowtransparency="true"/>
```

We can get the data from this *iframe* as:

```
var content=$("iframe").contents().find('body').html();
alert(content);
```