# selector elements from iframe in parent

Tags: jquery, html, select, iframe

I find that it's very hard to select elements in an iframe and make some action in my parent page. Here is my codes and it does not work.

In my parent codes:

```
//(JS PART)
var $currentIFrame = $('#screen'); 
   alert($currentIFrame.contents().find("#abc").type);

//(body part)
  <iframe id="screen" name="screen" width="100%" height="100%" src="test.php">

                   </iframe>
```

in my iframe files:

```
//(body part)
<input type="text" id="abc" name="abc">
```

While, the result is "undefined" instead of "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched
>   element.

```
alert($currentIFrame.contents().find("#abc").attr('type'));
```

---

EDIT: If the iframe is different domain, you cannot access the contents of it due to **[Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)**:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://www.ebay.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: To access the contents of the iframe.

Comment: The answer is like, what is the purpose of .find()..? --> it is used to find elements..    *** I am asking find itself enough in this context right..?

Comment: No you need to use `contents()` to access the iframe

Comment: This should [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814411/getting-the-html-content-of-an-iframe-using-jquery) felix explaining it

Comment: I made a test but your answers are all not works. Here I use Ebay just for a test, it should return "checkbox" but nothing return: http://jsfiddle.net/PL2Qy/

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `.attr()`:

```
  alert($currentIFrame.contents().find("#abc").attr('type'));
```

Comment: This should work. Can you craete the fiddle for problem.

Comment: I made a example of ebay: jsfiddle.net/PL2Qy

Answer (score 1):

try using find

```
var element = $currentIFrame.find("#abc").attr('type'));
```

Comment: I made a test but your answers are all not works. Here I use Ebay just for a test, it should return "checkbox" but nothing return: http://jsfiddle.net/PL2Qy/

Answer (score 1):

You should pay attention on the 2 factors:

- 1 - frame should be from the same domain, otherwise you'll be able do
  nothing;
- 2 - when you try to get elements inside of the iframe - it must be
  already loaded.

`var frame = $( '#frameSelector' );
frame.load( function(){
    var element = frame.contents().find( '.selector' );
});`